# How to save sent messages in Outlook to the same folder as message being replied to?

Tags: mac, ms-office, folders, productivity

If I am replying to an email in Folder "TEST", how do I get a reply to automatically go to the Folder "TEST" as opposed to the Sent folder?  This helps with productivity so that I don't have to move the responses to the folders they are in.  If the message responding to resides in the inbox, the response will go to the Sent folder and can be moved to another folder at another time.

Answer (score 0):

On the Windows desktop version, there is a setting that I have not found in the Mac version:
[image: Outlook Windows]

Since this is a function of the application and not exchange server, I don't think you can replicate this on the Mac version.

I could not find any way to make Rules work on the Sent Mailbox.